# Need to access an image from HTML Page Editor

Tags: wordpress

I have an image called "image-a.gif" in my WP images directory.

My question is, I am inside a page in the WP dashboard, specifically within the HTML editor page and need to access this image-a.gif from within the editor.

I am placing inside a div using img src="image-a.gif" but unsure how to get to it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your in the WordPress page editor you can add images from the media library by clicking the add image icon.

[image]

Next choose add image from media library choose the image and click insert and WordPress will add the code to the page editor.